What does the AND operator '&' do in "& tee"?
In my development environment there exists an alias that writes stdout to a specific file.
It uses pipe with tee, e.g., du -h | & tee /tmp/diskUsage.
I understand that AND operator makes whatever it precedes a file descriptor instead of filename, say by 2>&1 we are redirecting stderr to stdout instead of a file called "1" in current dir.
However, for the usage | & tee, there is nothing meaningful after '&' and before "tee", what does it do in this case?

& only indicates a file descriptor in certain very specific situations. In other places, like this one, it means something completely different. Also, spaces are extremely important delimiters in shell syntax, and adding or removing them may drastically change the meaning of a command; in this case, the space you have between | and & will cause a syntax error.

Thanks for pointing that out. I tried and found it indeed cause parser error in my macOS, but in redhat it works fine. Seems to be platform specific.

Oh, yeah, even without the space |& is only in recent versions of bash, and macOS comes with an old version of bash (v3.2.57) that doesn't have it. And also, the default interactive shell in macOS is zsh, which doesn't support |& at all.

@GordonDavisson zsh supports |&. See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Simple-Commands-_0026-Pipelines

|& is shorthand for "pipe both stderr and stdout from the left hand program to the right hand program".
Basically, tee will receive both normal output and error output muxed together, not just stdout as plain | would do normally.
Or to quote GNU docs:

If ‘|&’ is used, command1’s standard error, in addition to its standard output, is connected to command2’s standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for 2>&1 |. This implicit redirection of the standard error to the standard output is performed after any redirections specified by command1.


Understood, many thanks for teaching. The reference to GNU doc is greatly appreciated ;)
